# Explaination on error viewing status of Google Drive API v3 upload using next_chunk() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, upload, google-drive-api

I am trying to do a resumable upload to google drive using the v3 api. I want to be able to display a status bar of the upload. I can get it to upload easily and quickly if I do not need a status bar because I can use the .execute() function and it uploads. The problems arise when I want to upload the files in chunks. I've seen a few solutions to this on here and other places, but they don't seem to work.

This is my code for uploading:

```
    CHUNK_SIZE = 256*1024
    file_metadata = {'name': file_name, 'parents': [folder_id]} #Metadata for the file we are going to upload
    media = MediaFileUpload(file_path, mimetype='application/zip',chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE, resumable=True) 
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id')
    progress = progressBarUpload(file) #create instance off progress bar class
    progress.exec_() #execute it
    progress.hide() #hide it off the screen after
    print(file_name + " uploaded successfully")
    return 1 #returns 1 if it was successful
```

The progress bar calls a thread for my gui which then uses the next_chunk() function, this code is here:

```
signal = pyqtSignal(int)
def __init__(self, file):
    super(ThreadUpload,self).__init__()
    self.file = file

def run(self):
    done = False
    while done == False:
        status, done = self.file.next_chunk()
        print("status->",status)
        if status:
            value = int(status.progress() * 100)
            print("Uploaded",value,"%")
            self.signal.emit(value)
```

The problem I am getting is that my status = None.

If I use this code it works correctly, but I cannot view the status of the upload using this method. There is a .execute() added which makes it work. I get rid of the next_chunk() part when doing it this way:

```
    CHUNK_SIZE = 256*1024
    file_metadata = {'name': file_name, 'parents': [folder_id]} #Metadata for the file we are going to upload
    media = MediaFileUpload(file_path, mimetype='application/zip',chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE, resumable=True) 
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
```

The first method doesn't work whether I use it in the progress bar thread or not, the second method works both ways every time. I use the progress bar to view the status for downloads and a few other things and it works very well, so I'm pretty confident its the fact my status = None when downloading that is the problem.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're comparing the response from the request (`done` variable in your case) with `False`, this condition will never return `True` because the response is either `None` or an object with the object ID once the upload procces has finished. This is the code I tested and worked succesfully:

```
   CHUNK_SIZE = 256 * 1024
    file_metadata = {'name': "Test resumable"}  # Metadata for the file we are going to upload
    media = MediaFileUpload("test-image.jpg", mimetype='image/jpeg', chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE, resumable=True)
    request = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id')
    response = None
    while response is None:
        status, response = request.next_chunk()
        if status:
            print(status.progress())

    print(response)
    print("uploaded successfully")
```

For your case, you could change these 2 lines:

```
done = False
while done == False:
```

For this:

```
done = None
while done is None:
```

Comment: Thank you, tried it out there works great. Never even considered it wasn't supposed to return True because when using the same technique with uploading it returns True or False depending on if its done uploading or not.