# Uploading a very large file to google drive using the drive api using python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, resumable

I am looking to upload a very large zip file (several hundred GBs) from my remote server to my google drive using the drive api v3. I tried following [a tutorial at *Toward Data Science*](https://towardsdatascience.com/uploading-files-to-google-drive-directly-from-the-terminal-using-curl-2b89db28bb06%20but) but it defers the use of resumable uploads to the drive api documentation, which isn't very beginner friendly. Other questions on this matter don't handle the file sizes I am handling. They also don't mention the issue of keeping the access-token valid for the time the file is being uploaded. I also found [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45890948/16476327) during my search. However, it is again a "multi-part" upload method.

Any help would be appreciated. I am looking to automate this using a python script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your question, are these threads useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61759449/7108653 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/64587769/7108653 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/60528771

Comment: @Tanaike https://stackoverflow.com/a/60536138/16476327 is quite relevant. However, I am unable to piece-together the chunking that I'll need to get from the test file to the large file. Where do I add the chunk_size parameter in this answer?

Comment: Your file size is too big for one shot upload. Uploading files always involves a request timeout, max request size, etc... That's why you endup to documentation talking about resumable uploads. BTW, have a look to the GDrive API, its intended use and service limits.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The sample script of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60536138 uses a single chank. If you want to use multiple chunks, you can see ["HTTP - multiple requests" of this official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#uploading).

Answer (score 0):

this is PHP example but maybe help you
in php Upload Like this

```
public function uploadFileChunk($uploadFile)
{
    try {
        if ($uploadFile) {
            $client = $this->getClient();
            $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
            $uploadFileExp = explode('\\', $uploadFile);
            $uploadFileName = end($uploadFileExp);
            $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
            $file->setName($uploadFileName);
            $chunkSizeBytes = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
            $client->setDefer(true);
            $request = $service->files->create($file);
            $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
                $client,
                $request,
                'application/octet-stream',
                null,
                true,
                $chunkSizeBytes
            );
            $status = false;
            $handle = fopen($uploadFile, "rb");
            $fileSize = filesize($uploadFile);
            $total_records = (int)($fileSize/$chunkSizeBytes);
            $media->setFileSize($fileSize);
            $i = 0;
            while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
                ++$i;
                $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
                $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
            }

            $result = false;
            if ($status != false) {
                $result = $status;
            }

            fclose($handle);
            $client->setDefer(false);
            $fileId = $result->id;
            return $fileId;


        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

And you need Refresh Your access token for uploading large files like 50GB+

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshToken['refresh_token']);

    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
```